# How do I find the value of 2 variables when 2 simultaneous equations have no real solutions?

Tags: systems-of-equations

I have been struggling with this question for a while now which says if these 2 simultaneous equations
$ax-3y=b-3$ and $3x+y(a+8)=-b$ have no real solution, then what's the value of a and b. I have tried using matrices but with no result. Say I was able to find the a value, how do I use it to find b?

Comment: Do you know how to tell whether a system of two (linear) simultaneous equations has exactly one solution, without actually solving it? It's usually phrased using matrices.

Comment: Recall that for two lines in the plane there are three different solutions: none, exactly one, infinitely many. What situations do these correspond to graphically? Can you then tie that to the equations of the lines?